# jquery validator is not showing error message second of the form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I started using the jquery plugin for validation and am puzzled why it's not working, here is my javascript code for it: "

```
    $("#msform").validate({
            rules: {
                set3: {
                    required: true,
                    number: true,
            range: [15000,1000000]
                },

                companyName: {
                    required: true
                },

                set6: {
                    required: true
                },
                existingEmi: {
                    number: true
                },
                dobDay: {
                    required: true
                },
                dobMonth: {
                    required: true
                },
                dobYear: {
                    required: true
                },
                cityTextBox: {
                    required: true
                },
                set11: {
                    required: true,
                    number: true,
            range: [2000000,250000000]
                },
                annualNetProfit: {
                    required: true,
                    number: true,
            range: [300000,5000000]
                },
                name: {
                    required: true
                },
                mobile: {
                    required: true,
                    range: [7000000000, 9999999999]
                },
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                termsAndCondition: {
                    required: true
                }
            },
            messages: {
                set3: {
                    required: "Please provide your monthly income",
                    number: "Income cannot be characters"
                },

                companyName: {
                    required: "Please enter your company name."
                },

                set6: {
                    required: "Please select your mode of salary."
                },
                existingEmi: {
                    number: "EMI cannot be characters"
                },
                dobDay: {
                  required: "Please select your birth day."
                },
                dobMonth: {
                  required: "Please select your birth month."
                },
                dobYear: {
                  required: "Please select your birth year."
                },
                cityTextBox: {
                    required: "Please enter your city."
                },
                set11: {
                    required: "Please enter your annual turnover.",
                    number: "Annual turnover cannot be characters"
                },
                annualNetProfit: {
                    required: "Please enter your annual net profit.",
                    number: "Annual net profit cannot be characters"
                },
                name: {
                    required: "Please enter your first name."
                },
                mobile: {
                    required: "Please enter your mobile number.",
                    range: "Please enter a valid mobile number."
                },
                email: {
                    required: "Please enter your email address.",
                    email: "Please enter a valid email address."
                },
                termsAndCondition: {
                    required: "Please accept the terms and condition to submit the form. ",
                }
            },
           errorPlacement:
           function(error, element){
                var name = $(element).attr("name");
                error.appendTo($("#" + name + "_validate"));
           }
});
```

And Form code was

```
 <form name="offer" action="" method="post" id="msform">

      <!-- Type of occupation -->
      <fieldset id="prof_type">
          <h2 class="fs-title">I am</h2>

          <input type="hidden" name="offeringTypeId" value="47" id="offeringTypeId_10">
          <input type="hidden" value="3" name="product"/>
          <input type="hidden" value="6,2135,1,9,10,23,21,14,69,15,8,3,44,56,20,2127,2,660,57,53,54,51,52,62,61,58,55,64,65,63,59,41,60,1765,1254,48,1292,1767,2015,1763,1762,1766,1768,1797,1798,1799,1808,1809,1810,1832,527,2188,2155" id="allPrincipalIds" name="allPrincipalIds"/>
          <input type="hidden" value="Y" name="apnaExchangePolicy"/>
          <input type="hidden" value="Y" name="isNewWebsite"/>
          <input type="hidden" name = "monthlyIncome" id="monthlyIncome" value="" />
          <input type="hidden" name="annualIncome" value="" />

<input type="hidden" name="AdGroupId" id="AdGroupId" value="<?php echo $_COOKIE['AdGroupId'];?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="ef_id" id="ef_id" value="<?php echo $_COOKIE['ef_id'];?>" />     

          <div id="occupation">
          <input type="radio" name="occupation" title="Salaried" value="1" />
          <input type="radio" name="occupation" title="Self-employed Professional" value="11" />
          <input type="radio" name="occupation" title="Self-employed Business" value="2" />

          </div>
          <br />
          <!-- <input class="next action-button" name="next" type="button" value="Next"> -->
      </fieldset>

      <!-- Company Name -->
      <fieldset id="work">
          <h2 class="fs-title">I work for</h2>
          <div class="tooltip tooltip-west">
              <span class="tooltip-item">?</span>
              <span class="tooltip-content">Enter the name of the Company for which you work, there may be special offers available.</span>
          </div>

          <input type="text" name="companyName" id="company" value="" placeholder="Enter your company name" class="typeahead" style="font-size:18px;border-radius:0;width:50%;" />

          <div id="companyName_validate"></div>

          <a class="previous">
              <div class="scroll-btn-prev"></div>
          </a>

          <!--<input class="previous action-button" name="previous" type="button" value="Previous" />-->
          <input class="next action-button" name="next" type="button" value="Next" />
      </fieldset>

      <!-- Monthly Salary -->
      <fieldset id="sal">
          <h2 class="fs-title">My net monthly take home salary is</h2>
          <div class="tooltip tooltip-west">
              <span class="tooltip-item">?</span>
              <span class="tooltip-content" style="width: 30em;">Enter the monthly net take home salary (after deducting PF, Income tax, incentives and any other deductions)</span>
          </div>

          <input name="set3" type="text" id="set3" placeholder="Your Monthly Income" />
          <div id="set3_validate"></div>

          <a class="previous">
              <div class="scroll-btn-prev"></div>
          </a>
          <!--
          <input class="previous action-button" name="previous" type="button" value="Previous" />-->

          <input class="next action-button" name="next" type="button" value="Next" />
      </fieldset>

       <!-- Annual Turnover (If Self Employed) -->
      <fieldset id="tur">
          <h2 class="fs-title">My annual turnover is</h2>
          <div class="tooltip tooltip-west">
              <span class="tooltip-item">?</span>
              <span class="tooltip-content" style="width: 18em;">Enter Gross turnover for the last financial year as per the filed ITR.</span>
          </div>

          <input name="set11" type="text" id="set11" placeholder="Your Annual Turnover" />
          <div id="set11_validate"></div>

          <a class="previous">
              <div class="scroll-btn-prev"></div>
          </a>
          <!--
          <input class="previous action-button" name="previous" type="button" value="Previous" />-->

          <input class="next action-button" name="next" type="button" value="Next" />
      </fieldset>

      <!-- Place -->
      <fieldset>
          <h2 class="fs-title">I am currently residing in</h2>
          <div class="tooltip tooltip-west">
              <span class="tooltip-item">?</span>
              <span class="tooltip-content">City of residence is required because Loan Eligibility norms often vary from city to city.</span>
          </div>

          <input type="input" value="0" name="city" id="city" class="required" style="display:none;"/>
          <div id="cityTextBox">
          <input type="radio" name="cityTextBox" title="Mumbai" value="57" />
          <input type="radio" name="cityTextBox" title="New Delhi" value="63" />
          <input type="radio" name="cityTextBox" title="Bangalore" value="9" />
          <input type="radio" name="cityTextBox" title="Chennai" value="20" />

          <div id="set10">
              <select id="set10" name="set10">
                  <option value="">Other City</option>
                  <option value="1">Ahmedabad</option>
                  <option value="2">Akola</option>
                  <option value="3">Allahabad</option>
                  <option value="4">Alwar</option>
                  <option value="5">Amritsar</option>
                  <option value="6">Anand</option>
                  <option value="7">Ankleshwar</option>
                  <option value="8">Aurangabad</option>
                  <option value="10">Bareilly</option>

              </select>
          </div>
          <input id="city_but" class="next" name="next" type="button" value="Next" />
          </div>
          <div id="set10_validate"></div>

          <a class="previous">
              <div class="scroll-btn-prev"></div>
          </a>
          <!--
          <input class="previous action-button" name="previous" type="button" value="Previous" />
          <input class="next action-button" name="next" type="button" value="Next" />-->
      </fieldset>

       <!-- Payment Method -->
      <fieldset id="sal_acct">
          <h2 class="fs-title">My salary account is with</h2>
          <div class="tooltip tooltip-west">
              <span class="tooltip-item">?</span>
              <span class="tooltip-content" style="width: 20em;">Please select how you receive your salary.</span>
          </div>

          <input type="hidden" name="salaryReceivedAs" id="sal_method" value="" />
          <input type="hidden" name="salaryAccountWithBank" id="sal_bank" value="" />

          <div id="bank">
          <input type="radio" name="bank" title="SBI" value="6" />
          <input type="radio" name="bank" title="HDFC Bank" value="12" />
          <input type="radio" name="bank" title="ICICI Bank" value="1" />
          <input type="radio" name="bank" title="Axis Bank (UTI)" value="10" />
          <div id="set6">
              <select id="set6" name="set6">
                  <option value="">Other Bank</option>
                  <option value="2">IDBI Bank</option>
                  <option value="3">CITI Bank</option>
                  <option value="4">CITI Financial</option>
                  <option value="5">IDBI Home Finance Ltd</option>
                  <option value="7">RBS</option>
                  <option value="8">HSBC Bank</option>
                  <option value="9">HDFC Ltd.</option>
                               </select>
          </div>
          <input type="radio" name="bank" title="Receive by cash" value="100" />
          <input type="radio" name="bank" title="Receive by cheque" value="101" />
          <input id="bank_but" class="next" name="next" type="button" value="Next" />
          </div>
          <div id="set6_validate"></div>

          <a class="previous">
              <div class="scroll-btn-prev"></div>
          </a>
          <!--
          <input class="previous action-button" name="previous" type="button" value="Previous" />-->
      </fieldset>

      <!-- Existing credit card details if any -->
      <fieldset id="ecredit">
          <h2 class="fs-title">My Existing Credit limit is</h2>
          <div class="tooltip tooltip-west">
              <span class="tooltip-item">?</span>
              <span class="tooltip-content">Please enter the limit of existing credit card if any.</span>
          </div>
          <input name="creditLimitAmt" class="Optional" type="text" id="set7" placeholder="Credit Card limit" style="" />
           <!--<label for="existingCre">Credit Card limit</label>-->
          <div id="existingCre_validate"></div>

          <a class="previous">
              <div class="scroll-btn-prev"></div>
          </a>

          <input name="existCRE" id="existCRE" type="hidden" />
          <input name="tenure" id="tenure" type="hidden" value="2" />
          <!--<input class="previous action-button" name="previous" type="button" value="Previous" />-->
          <input class="next action-button" id="emi_but" name="next" type="button" value="Next" />
      </fieldset>

      <!-- Date of Birth -->
      <fieldset>
          <h2 class="fs-title">My date of birth is</h2>
          <div class="tooltip tooltip-west">
              <span class="tooltip-item">?</span>
              <span class="tooltip-content" style="width: 27em;">Enter the date of birth as mentioned on the PAN card. Accurate age helps us to compute the best loan offer.</span>
          </div>

                      <select class="widthDay" id="dobDay" name="dobDay">
                          <option value="">Date</option>
                          <option value="1">1</option>
                          <option value="2">2</option>
                          <option value="3">3</option>
                          <option value="4">4</option>
                          <option value="5">5</option>
                          <option value="6">6</option>
                          <option value="7">7</option>
                          <option value="8">8</option>
                          <option value="9">9</option>
                          <option value="10">10</option>
                          <option value="11">11</option>
                          <option value="12">12</option>
                          <option value="13">13</option>
                          <option value="14">14</option>
                          <option value="15">15</option>
                          <option value="16">16</option>
                          <option value="17">17</option>
                          <option value="18">18</option>
                          <option value="19">19</option>
                          <option value="20">20</option>
                          <option value="21">21</option>
                          <option value="22">22</option>
                          <option value="23">23</option>
                          <option value="24">24</option>
                          <option value="25">25</option>
                          <option value="26">26</option>
                          <option value="27">27</option>
                          <option value="28">28</option>
                          <option value="29">29</option>
                          <option value="30">30</option>
                          <option value="31">31</option>
                      </select>
                      <select class="widthMonth" id="dobMonth" name="dobMonth">
                          <option value="">Month</option>
                          <option value="01">Jan</option>
                          <option value="02">Feb</option>
                          <option value="03">Mar</option>

                          <option value="04">Apr</option>
                          <option value="05">May</option>
                          <option value="06">Jun</option>
                          <option value="07">Jul</option>
                          <option value="08">Aug</option>
                          <option value="09">Sep</option>

                          <option value="10">Oct</option>
                          <option value="11">Nov</option>
                          <option value="12">Dec</option>
                      </select>
                      <select class="widthYear" id="dobYear" name="dobYear">
                          <option value="">Year</option>
                          <option value="1992">1992</option>
                          <option value="1991">1991</option>
                          <option value="1990">1990</option>
                          <option value="1989">1989</option>
                          <option value="1988">1988</option>
                          <option value="1987">1987</option>
                          <option value="1986">1986</option>
                          <option value="1985">1985</option>
                          <option value="1984">1984</option>
                          <option value="1983">1983</option>
                          <option value="1982">1982</option>
                          <option value="1981">1981</option>
                          <option value="1980">1980</option>
                          <option value="1979">1979</option>
                          <option value="1978">1978</option>
                          <option value="1977">1977</option>
                          <option value="1976">1976</option>
                          <option value="1975">1975</option>
                          <option value="1974">1974</option>
                          <option value="1973">1973</option>
                          <option value="1972">1972</option>
                          <option value="1971">1971</option>
                          <option value="1970">1970</option>
                          <option value="1969">1969</option>
                          <option value="1968">1968</option>
                          <option value="1967">1967</option>
                          <option value="1966">1966</option>
                          <option value="1965">1965</option>
                          <option value="1964">1964</option>
                          <option value="1963">1963</option>
                          <option value="1962">1962</option>
                          <option value="1961">1961</option>
                          <option value="1960">1960</option>
                          <option value="1959">1959</option>
                          <option value="1958">1958</option>
                          <option value="1957">1957</option>
                          <option value="1956">1956</option>
                          <option value="1955">1955</option>
                          <option value="1954">1954</option>
                          <option value="1953">1953</option>
                          <option value="1952">1952</option>
                          <option value="1951">1951</option>
                          <option value="1950">1950</option>
                      </select>
                      <br>
          <div id="dobDay_validate"></div>
          <div id="dobMonth_validate"></div>
          <div id="dobYear_validate"></div>
          <input type="hidden" name="age" id="age" />
          <input type="hidden" name="offeringTypeId" value="42">
                      <input type="hidden" name="purpose" value="" id="hiddenPurpose">
                      <input type="hidden" name="occupationId" value="1">
                      <input type="hidden" name="jTag" value="comp">
          <a class="previous">
              <div class="scroll-btn-prev"></div>
          </a>
          <!--
          <input class="previous action-button" name="previous" type="button" value="Previous" />-->
          <input class="next action-button" id="dob_but" name="next" type="button" value="Next" />
      </fieldset>

       <!-- Personal Details -->
      <fieldset id="personal">
          <h2 class="fs-title">Personal Details</h2>
          <div class="tooltip tooltip-west" style="top: 32%;left: 78%;">
              <span class="tooltip-item">?</span>
              <span class="tooltip-content" style="width: 8em;">Enter full name as it appears on your  PAN card.</span>
          </div>
          <div class="tooltip tooltip-west" style="top: 47%;left: 78%;">
              <span class="tooltip-item">?</span>
              <span class="tooltip-content" style="width: 10em;">Please give correct mobile number as a code will be sent to validate your number.</span>
          </div>
          <div class="tooltip tooltip-west" style="top: 63%;left: 78%;">
              <span class="tooltip-item">?</span>
              <span class="tooltip-content" style="width: 10em;">On this address, We will mail you offer details, Documents needed and useful tips on negotiating a good deal.</span>
          </div>


          <div id="gender">
          <input type="radio" name="gender" title="Mr." value="male" />
          <input type="radio" name="gender" title="Mrs." value="female" />
          <input type="radio" name="gender" title="Miss" value="female" />
          </div>

          <input type="hidden" value="Both" name="rateType" />

          <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="First Name" />
          <input name="lname" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" /><br>
          <div id="name_validate"></div>

          <input name="mobile" type="text" placeholder="Phone" maxlength="10" /><br>
          <div id="mobile_validate"></div>

          <input name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email" /><br>
          <div id="email_validate"></div>
          <input class="action-button open-cc" type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </fieldset>
  </form>
```

First of the form validation is working fine after DOB the validation is not working when submit the form without filling the First name,mobile,email it not showing the error message and validation also not working.

I tried to hide validation of DOB and again add the validation it was working fine after the DOB the validation is not working. Where did wrong.

Comment: seems to work fine for me https://plnkr.co/edit/9U2RGZ2XtS1OMC6dqAz1?p=preview

Comment: but it does not working for me

Comment: could you create a jsfiddle/plunker and replicate it?

Comment: in my submit 
    $(".open-cc").click(function(){ 
        var tat = $('input[name|="set11"]').val();
        $('input[name|="annualIncome"]').val(tat);
            $('input[name|="monthlyIncome"]').val(parseInt(tat/12));
       $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "http://result.html",
          data: $('#msform').serialize(),
          success: function(responseText){
            if(responseText){
                        url_redirect({url: "http://mobile-validation.html"});      
             }
           
          }
       });

Comment: @deep,https://plnkr.co/edit/q1nIMGF2gUuR1ReJBm96?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Every thing is working fine, but you have to change the error messages color so  that user can identify the error messages from labels. Put a css like:

```
.error{
  color: red;
}
```

It will show the error text in red color.

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/66bw5u4h/22/)

Answer (score 0):

Things will work fine if you make the following changes in your plunker

1: Remove  style="overflow:hidden;" from html tag.

2: Add script.js into your plunker, you head tag should be like this.

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">

  <script data-require="jquery" data-semver="3.0.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>


</head>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/9hixFbI2viXitWbOsC55?p=preview

The problem with your updated code is that with submit button you are also 
binding this function on click,

```
$(".open-cc").click(function(){

        var tat = $('input[name|="set11"]').val();
        $('input[name|="annualIncome"]').val(tat);

            $('input[name|="monthlyIncome"]').val(parseInt(tat/12));

       $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "https://ppp.apna.com/simple-search-result.html",
          data: $('#msform').serialize(),
          success: function(responseText){
            if(responseText){
                        url_redirect({url: "http://ppp.apna.com/mobile-validation.html"});                      
                        url_redirect({url: "http://ppp.apna.com/mobile-validation.html"});                      
             }

          }
       });
       return false;
    });
```

This code is getting fired before the validation on form submit and causing validation to break.

you should put the code in a private function and call it once the validation is successful.

Private function

```
var onValidationSuccessful = function()
{
 var tat = $('input[name|="set11"]').val();
            $('input[name|="annualIncome"]').val(tat);

                $('input[name|="monthlyIncome"]').val(parseInt(tat/12));

           $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "https://ppp.apna.com/simple-search-result.html",
              data: $('#msform').serialize(),
              success: function(responseText){
                if(responseText){
                            url_redirect({url: "http://ppp.apna.com/mobile-validation.html"});                      
                            url_redirect({url: "http://ppp.apna.com/mobile-validation.html"});                      
                 }

              }
           });
           return false;

}
```

and in the validate method add below property.

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
            onValidationSuccessful();
        }
```

Comment: when put all jquery in head it shows jquery is not defined

Comment: is the code in your machine is different than the plunker you provided ? I was able to fix only those error which were seen in the plunker

Comment: where can i put the function and called it again. It is call the simple search form and mobile validation. user will get verification code to verify it

Comment: did u got it working now ? i updated the answer above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128708/discussion-between-sakthi-and-deep).